# Define pretty sets in LaTeX; esp., how to do the condition-separator?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

E.g., I have this set:

```
\{ \alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^* \}
```

Here, I use `|` as the separator for the condition part. But LaTeX doesn't add any spaces around it, thus it looks a bit strange/wrong. I could manually add some space here but I wondered if there is some more "correct" way. E.g. also to make it behave similar as `:` (which I actually want to behave different here; in this case, `:` adds too much space in front of it for my taste).

---

Related questions: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209863/how-to-add-mathematical-notation-of-a-set) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253077/how-do-you-create-a-set-in-latex).

Comment: I had an additional question regarding this topic, which you may find [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25398/7160) if you are interested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I sometimes do something a little more evil

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[2]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}%
 { #1 \,\delimsize| \,\mathopen{} #2 }
\begin{document}
\[
\Set*{ x }{ x>0 }
\]
\end{document}
```

and thus hide the symbol inside the construction. Both a starred and non-starred `\Set` is created with `\Set*` autoscaling braces and vertical line is used.

Update August 2014: I no longer recommend a two argument solution, but rather this as I feel it gives an interface much closer to the mathematical meaning

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\providecommand\given{} % so it exists
\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{
   \nonscript\,#1\vert \allowbreak \nonscript\,\mathopen{}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}%
 { \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]} #1 }
\begin{document}
\[
\Set*{ x \given x>0 }
\]
\end{document}
```

BTW: notice the added `\mathopen{}` withput it `\Set{ X \given -a < x < a}` would give us the wrong `-a` (a subtraction minus, not a sign minus)

Update March 2015: Moved the `\allowbreak` in front of the proceeding inserted space. Then that space disappears if a line break happens.

Comment: Hehe, yea, I actually use some similar construct now. Whereby I used `\newcommand`. Is there any advantage with `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`?

Comment: Test the document, it defines more than one command, try `\Set[\big]{...}{...}`

Comment: Hm, it seems something is wrong there. I get the error `Runaway argument?
./texdefs.tex:33: Paragraph ended before \DeclarePairedDelimiterX was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.33 
     
? `

Comment: @Albert: @daleif 's code works OK in my system. The error message  suggests that you forgot a closing brace. If that's not the case, we'll need to see the problematic code to detect the problem.

Comment: My code: `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\SetC[2]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{ #1 \,\delimsize|\, #2 }`

Comment: @Albert: Well, with just that line we surely can detect any problem; we need a complete, minimal version of the problematic code.

Comment: @albert: which version of mathtools? It needs version 1.10 from Feb 2011, and earlier version had a similar macro but with different options, it was reimplemented to provide an easier interface. So I guess you need to update your LaTeX installation

Comment: @daleif: Ah, I guess that's it. It's from 2010. It's the mac distribution [here](http://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: @albert: then run the updating utility, there should be one in the TeX folder somewhere under the applications folder

Comment: There's a closing brace `}` missing after `\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]` in the second block of code.

Answer (score 17):

You should use `\mid` instead of `|`. And use `\colon` instead of `:` after the existential quantifier (although I would just put a thinspace).

Comment: I started to use `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}` now. What about `\bigm|` instead of `\mid`? Is there a difference except that it is slightly bigger?

Comment: I would think `:` might be correct there whereas `\colon` is more for `F\colon A\to B`

Comment: The problem with `\mid` is that it is not a fence, thus not scalable

Comment: If you use big braces, you should indeed use `\bigm|` instead of `\mid` since `\mid` is not defined as a delimiter and thus cannot be used with `\bigm`.

Answer (score 9):

The [`braket`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/braket) package contains a `\set` command which does what you want :

```
\set{\alpha \in \Sigma^\omega | \exists^\omega n : \alpha [0,n] \notin \Sigma^* a_1 \Sigma^* a_2 \dotsb a_n \Sigma^*}
```

It also defines `\Set`, where the first `|` is expandable, which allows to properly typeset sets like

```
\Set{x| x\in\mathbb R, |x|<\frac12 }
```