# Spacing of characters in a mathematical set, displayed inline in paragraph

Tags: math-mode, spacing, inline

I have a mathematical set notation that I want to display inline in a paragraph of text. However, when I write this, the output is not very beautiful:

```
$\{ (w_j,\dots,w_{j+n-1}) | 0 \leq j \leq k-1-n\}$
```

The curly braces look a bit too small, but it's bearable. What's worse is the spacing, I think: the curly braces are too close to the opening parenthesis on the left side and the "n" on the right side. The same with the pipe symbol in the middle: it's practically glued to the closing parenthesis and the "0".

Overall the tight spacing makes the definition difficult to read. So I wonder if there is a "better" way to write the above set, so that the output is more esthetically pleasing.

Comment: Very much related: [Define pretty sets in LaTeX; esp., how to do the condition-separator?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13634/1235) (possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\left\{ ... \mid ... \right\}`. The spacing of the curly braces looks fine to me, but if you insist on more spacing you can add a `\,` between the `\left\{` and the `(`. So, the complete equation becomes

```
$\left\{ (w_j,\dots,w_{j+n-1}) \mid 0 \leq j \leq k-1-n \right\}$
```

or, with the extra spacing

```
$\left\{\, (w_j,\dots,w_{j+n-1}) \mid 0 \leq j \leq k-1-n\,\right\}$
```

Comment: I'd like to add that in general `\left...\right` with in inline mathematics, should be used with extreme care, because they can easily become too large, and thus alter the line space

Comment: I second that. Also, if you use `\left\{` and `\right\}`, it makes sense to use `\middle|` instead of `\mid`, so that the vertical bar has the same size as the curly braces (note that `\mid` is not scalable).

Comment: Ah, I did not know about the difference between `\mid` and `\middle`. I will revise my answer later this evening, explaining a bit more about delimiter sizing and stuff like that. Thanks for the additional info.