# \mathrel conflict with \left,\right,\middle

Tags: spacing, amsmath, mathtools

I refer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13634/7160) and particularly to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13634/define-pretty-sets-in-latex-esp-how-to-do-the-condition-separator/13637#13637). I defined `\set` by

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
...
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[2]{\{}{\}}{#1 \mathrel{\delimsize|} #2}
```

where `\mathrel{\delimsize|}` imitates `\mid`, which itself is of math relation type but not scaleable.

Although `\set[\big]{...}{...}`, `\set[\Big]{...}{...}` etc. work fine, the starred-form `\set*{...}{...}` does not. The problem is that, in this case, `\delimsize` expands to `\middle` and `\mathrel{\middle|}` leads to an error, which can easily be reproduced:

```
\left\{x \mathrel{\middle|} y\right\}
```

I could define `\set` alternatively like

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setnew[2]{\{}{\}}{#1 \;\delimsize|\; #2}
```

which should produce in most cases the same spaces around `|` as the version above. However, there is a difference if a set is in scriptstyle:

```
A_{\set{x}{y}}
```

puts no spaces around `|`, whereas

```
A_{\setnew{x}{y}}
```

still prints `\;|\;`.

Do you know a way to make `\mathrel` and `\middle` compatible?

Comment: Similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5502

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No space is inserted in script or scriptscript styles if you precede `\;` with `\nonscript`:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setnew[2]{\{}{\}}{%
  #1 \mathclose{}\nonscript\;\delimsize|\nonscript\;\mathopen{} #2%
}
```

Another solution that avoids `\nonscript` is

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[2]{\{}{\}}
  {#1 \mathrel{}\mathclose{}\delimsize|\mathopen{}\mathrel{} #2}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem :-) In addition, if anyone knows a solution for the other version, `\set`, I would be glad if you posted it, too.

Comment: `\left`, `\right` and `\middle` must be at the same brace level.

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Great! Your second solution is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Actually the first one is more efficient.

Comment: The first solution (\setnew) leads to odd spacing in, eg, "\setnew{A}{-B}". Probably adding a \mathopen{} before the second argument helps.

Comment: @pglpm I agree.

Comment: @pglpm see the mathtools manual for the one arg `\Set` macro, it adds `\mathopen` for that very reason.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable in using the alternative spacing you suggest:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\setnew[2]{\{}{\}}{#1 \;\delimsize|\; #2}
```

rather than

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[2]{\{}{\}}{#1 \mathrel{\delimsize|} #2}
```

then try adding

```
\usepackage{etex}
```

in your document preamble. `\middle` is part of an `etex` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would prefer `\set` to `\setnew`. Unfortunately, adding `\usepackage{etex}` didn't have an effect on both versions. The problem is not that the `\middle` command doesn't work but that it causes an error if I put `\mathrel{...}` around it.