# Creating a large "such that" symbol

Tags: macros, symbols

I'm using the following macro in my LaTeX document:

```
\newcommand{\suchthat}{\, \mid \,} % nice "such that"
```

so that set notation like the following looks nice:

```
\{x_n \suchthat n \in \mathbb{N}}
```

However, when I use such definitions of sets inside `\[...\]` and when I need to make the brackets bigger, the `\suchthat` symbol looks way to small.  Try compiling the following MWE as an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}                % for \mathbb font
\newcommand{\suchthat}{\, \mid \,}  % nice "such that"
\begin{document}

\noindent This looks fine:
\[ S = \left\{ x_n \suchthat n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \]

\noindent But this does not:
\[ S = \left\{ x_n \suchthat \frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \]

\end{document}
```

Is there something I can include in my macro to automatically resize the `suchthat` symbol as necessary?

Comment: It appears that this question has been discussed extensively: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25398/mathrel-conflict-with-left-right-middle, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/how-to-get-a-mid-binary-relation-that-grows, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/how-to-get-a-vertical-bar-which-is-longer-than-mid.  Not to be rude to jamaicanworm, but I think all the ground has been covered and perhaps this should be closed as a duplicate of, say, the second one.

Comment: I don't agree with this being a "duplicate".

Comment: Related Question: [Applying \middle outside of a \left \right group](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54052/applying-middle-outside-of-a-left-right-group)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\middle` only if there's a `\left` before it; we can check this using `\currentgrouptype` (`texdoc etex` for more information):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\suchthat}{\;\ifnum\currentgrouptype=16 \middle\fi|\;}

\begin{document}
\[
a \suchthat b\qquad\left\{\frac{a}{b}\suchthat x\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution seems simpler to use than @Ryan Reich's (i.e. no need for the `*` when calling `\suchthat`).  Does it have any disadvantages compared to Ryan's?  Also, would you recommend using `\;` or `\mathrel{}` for spacing?

Comment: Using `\;` or `\mathrel{}` can give different results only if before or after `\suchthat` you put a relation symbol, which is unlikely. I'd go with the explicit spacing or with `\ifnum\currentgrouplevel=16 \;\middle|\;\else\mid\fi` (but it seems overthinking).

Comment: @egreg: shouldn't the `\currentgrouplevel` in your last comment be a `\currentgrouptype`?

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Yes, of course. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 12):

This can be done with the `\middle` construction, which goes between `\left` and `\right` and resizes it to match:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\suchthat{%
 \@ifstar
  {\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}}
  {\mid}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \[ \left\{ \frac{a}{b} \suchthat* (a,b) = 1 \right\} \qquad \{ x \suchthat y \} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also handled the outer spaces a little more elegantly than with direct `\,` directives using the `\mathrel` primitive, which declares its operand to be a "relation", which I think "such that" is.

For convenience, my `\suchthat` takes a star that makes it resizable, since `\middle` is invalid outside `\left...\right`.  (In my opinion, fixed size is the default, so it is the unstarred version.)

Comment: I'd appreciate someone telling me how to do the equivalent of `\mathrel{\middle|}` or `\middle\mid`, either of which would, if valid, produce the correct spacing without the hack I used.

Comment: Cool.. Don't know why it never occurs to me to use `\middle`.

Comment: This is the first time I actually tested what you need to load to get it; turns out, nothing.  I seem to recall it's an eTeX extension, and as such, it always seems to get second-class treatment in tutorials I've read.  Funny how that happens to eTeX despite being twenty years old.

Comment: Thanks for showing this. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: `texdoc etex`, page 20, at the top.

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to pass a parameter to the `\suchthat` macro so that it can use a `\vphantom` to re size. This requires you to determine what portion should be used to re-size.

A better approach would be to pass the entire right hand side to the `\suchthat` macro.

Both produce similar results. Here is a comparison of the original on the left and new version on the right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\Oldsuchthat}{\, \mid \,}
\newcommand*{\suchthat}[1]{\left|\vphantom{#1}\right.}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  &S = \left\{ x_n \Oldsuchthat n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} &\quad
  &S = \left\{ x_n \suchthat{n} n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} \\[2.0ex]
  %
  &S = \left\{ x_n \Oldsuchthat \frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{N} \right\} &\quad
  &S = \left\{ x_n \suchthat{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{N} \right\}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

### Alternate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\Oldsuchthat}{\, \mid \,}
\newcommand*{\suchthat}[1]{\,\left|\, #1 \right.}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
&S = \left\{ x_n \Oldsuchthat n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} &\quad
%
&S = \left\{ x_n \suchthat{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \right\} \\[2.0ex]
&S = \left\{ x_n \Oldsuchthat \frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{N} \right\} &\quad
&S = \left\{ x_n \suchthat{\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```