# How to add mathematical notation of a set

Tags: math-operators

I'm pretty new to Latex, so please bare with me.

I'm trying to add this notation to my document:

[image]

I created the above picture from the [Online Latex Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), but it seems that when I try to apply the same code in my editor (TeXstudio), things are different...

For example, the above picture was produced using the code:

```
D=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{N}|1\leq x\leq 100 \right\}
```

But when I write it in my editor (enclosed in the $ sign of course), I get the following error when compiling:

> Undefined control sequence. $D=\left{x\in \mathbb

The funny thing is that I was still able to see the output in the preview window (even though the editor shows that this line has error in it).
That's the first problem.

The second problem is, although I can see the output in the preview window, it won't be the same as the output I get from the Online Latex Equation Editor.
While the Online Latex Equation Editor produces this:

[image]

My TeXstudio editor produces this:

[image]

Notice the distinction in the N symbol that denotes the set of natural numbers. It is different the what I intended, which is the first version, as it produced by the Online Latex Equation Editor.

What's wrong here? Am I missing a package or something?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For `\mathbb` you should have `\usepackage{amssymb}` (or `\usepackage{amsfonts}`, but better to have the bigger thing). The bar should be `\mid` for correct spacing. Note that `\left` and `\right` here serve no purpose.

Comment: @egreg Brilliant, thanks! this sort everything out!

Comment: @so.very.tired Please have a look at this post to see how to properly typeset `{...|...}` sets: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25411/11002

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A variant solution, also based on `mathtools`, with the cooperation of `xparse` allows for a syntax that's closer to mathematical writing: you just have to type something like`\set{x\in E;P(x)}` for the set-builder notation, or `\set{x_i}` for sets defined as lists.

Note that it's unnecessary to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

Illustration:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb Q}

\usepackage{xparse}
%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]{\{}{\}}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1} {#1\,\delimsize|\,\mathopen{}#2}}%{#1\:;\:#2}

\parindent = 0pt

\begin{document}

 \[ D = \set{x ∈ \N ; 1\leq x\leq 100} \]%

The delimiters adjust to the size of the contents in the * version:
\[ E = \set*{x ∈ \Q ; -\frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}}\]%

You also can have a manual adjustment with an optional argument to \verb+\set+:
\[ E = \set[\big]{x ∈ \Q ; -\mfrac{1}{2}\leq x \leq \mfrac{1}{2}}\]%

And you can define sets as simple lists:
\[ \text{Unit fractions}= \set*{\mfrac{1}{1}, \mfrac{1}{2},\mfrac{1}{3}, ... } \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would much more prefer `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\set[2]\{\}{#1\mathrel{}\mathclose{}\delimsize|\mathopen{}\mathrel{}#2}` :)

Comment: Once you have used it for a while you start to notice that a two arg syntax is not natural. I recommend marking the vertical line by a suitable \given macro and just a single arg. Then one can also use it for compressed notation like { x>2}

Comment: @daleif: Not sure to fully understand what you mean with ‘`marking` a suitable \given macro’. Having a syntax like `\set{x \given P(x)}`?

Comment: See the latest mathtools manual

Comment: @daleif: I see. I'll try to combine this approach with `;` used by `xparse` as a delimiter for the building property. However, I wonder how to use a `(semi)colon` instead of a vertical rule – I mean how to let the user choose his symbol as an optional argument.

Comment: That is why I recommend not using ; or | in the syntax. Use something that makes sense when read aloud

Comment: @daleif: I feel like you misunderstand me. What I meant is  some people write `;` or `:` as meaning `such that`. I would like to let them have this possibility. The other point is that I used `;` as a separator for `xparse` because it's not very much used in maths except precisely to mean ‘such that’, and because it's faster way to type than `\given`. So it's both easy to type *and* meaningful (even if you decide it will print a vertical rule).

Comment: I know it is faster, but it does not make it more readable. Plus having something in the code that has several meanings end up being rather annoying, because it makes double checking more difficult. Say you are using : as your syntax and you want to check all :'s in the doc. Then you get disturbed by the syntax colons. The same reason why I recommend no | anywhere in the code. It can have so many different meanings, that changing one of these need mathematical insight. Using different macro names for the different uses makes this easier plus makes the math part of the code easier to understand

Answer (score 15):

Probably the online editor loads the required package, which is `amssymb` (recommended for documents with math material). Note that `amsfonts` could be sufficient, but `amssymb` provides a richer supply of symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}} 
\newcommand{\nat}{\numberset{N}}}

\begin{document}

\[
D = \{\, x\in\nat \mid 1\le x\le 100 \,\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\left` and `\right` are not necessary here (and should be used only when really needed). Also the vertical bar should be `\mid` for better spacing. The thin spaces at both ends are a recommended, although optional, refinement.

The indirect definition of `\nat` (for “natural numbers”) is a trick that allows for uniform appearance of objects having the same nature. If you (or somebody else, read a fussy supervisor) later decide that boldface should be used, you can just change the definition of `\numberset`.

[image]

If you need plenty of set notations, it may be better to use `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\nat}{\numberset{N}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Set}[2]\{\}{%
  \, #1 \;\delimsize\vert\; #2 \,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
D=\Set{x\in\nat}{1\le x\le 100}\\
D=\Set[\big]{x\in\nat}{1\le x\le 100}\\
D=\Set[\Big]{x\in\nat}{1\le x\le 100}\\
D=\Set[\bigg]{x\in\nat}{1\le x\le 100}\\
D=\Set[\Bigg]{x\in\nat}{1\le x\le 100}\\
D=\Set*{x\in\nat}{1\le x\le \frac{200}{2}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

With the optional argument to `\Set` you can make the delimiters bigger. With `\Set*`, `\left` and `\right` are added.

[image]

Comment: See my comment to tohecz above. After having used the two arg approach for a while, I'd no longer recommend it. The `\Set{... \given... }` is a lot more natural to read.

Comment: @daleif Yes, but your example in the documentation is very hard to understand and there are better ways to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Hard how? And better how? By all means, if we can make it better.

Comment: Is `\;\delimsize\vert\;` the same as `\mathrel{\delimsize\vert}`? And are these both the same as `\mid` when the `\delimsize` is the default size?

Comment: @justin Not really the same, because `\delimsize` might be `\middle` in case you call `\Set*` and `\mathrel{\delimsize\vert}` would raise an error.