# big enough | in set

Tags: symbols

Can I adjust the symbol "|" in every set?

If we type the below code, the symbol "|" is too small. I know that I can use \big to adjust by manual. Is there a method for automatically adjust?

```
$\left\{ \sum\limits_{v\in e} f(v) |\ e\in E \right\}$
```

Comment: There is a nice macro for sets defined in the answer to the question [How to add mathematical notation of a set](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209863/how-to-add-mathematical-notation-of-a-set/209875#209875)

Comment: You shouldn't be typing  `|` in the first place. Try `\Bigm\vert`, which will give you the correct amount of horizontal spacing as well.

Answer (score 3):

The extension e-TeX (should be enabled with the LaTeX format) adds `\middle` to `\left` and `\right`. Also the sizes can be manually set using `\big` and friends. The latter looks nicer, because the index of the summation does not need to be included in the size of the delimiters. Also `\bigm` sets additional space around the symbol, because it is set as relational operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{ \sum\limits_{v\in e} f(v) \middle| e\in E \right\}\]
\[\Bigl\{\sum\limits_{v\in e} f(v) \Bigm| e\in E\Bigr\}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]