# New command with two definitions

Tags: math-mode, macros

I want to define a new command that serves two slightly different purposes. Can I define a new command called `\set` such that it's definition is chosen according to the number of argument(s) is(are) filled? I want **{1,2,3}** when I use `\set{1,2,3}` and I want **{x | x>0}** when I use `\set{x}{x>0}`.

Comment: I've removed the [tag:latex3] tag here -- it's not related to it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But thank heavens, the answers use it. :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: `xparse` uses LaTeX3? Oh my.... :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well I'm sure you know that `xparse` is part of the '3 in 2e' effort

Comment: @SeanAllred: I know of course

Comment: This is a direct duplicate of [How to add mathematical notation of a set](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209863/how-to-add-mathematical-notation-of-a-set/209875#209875).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, using `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` for example, making the second argument with `{}` behave like an optional argument then, i.e. using the `g` argument modifier.

Please note, that there is already a `\set{}` macro in the `braket` package, which provides for typesetting of sets, so I called the macro `\myset` instead and use `\set{...}` inside.

**In principle, this could be done with an trailing optional argument with `[]` too, which is perhaps even better, because this enforces you to distinguish between the list version and the conditional version of the set notation.**

**Edit** I've added the `\mybetterset{}[]` command as a variant to `\myset`, using the `[]` as 2nd optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myset}{mg}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \set{#1\;\vert\;#2}
  }{%
    \set{#1}%
  }%
}

%% The better command with [] as optional argument

   \NewDocumentCommand{\mybetterset}{mo}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \set{#1\;\vert\;#2}
  }{%
    \set{#1}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
$\myset{1,2,3}$

$\myset{x}{x > 0}$

$\mybetterset{1,2,3}$

$\mybetterset{x}[x>0]$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to add a comment about the `[]` until you edited it in :) That's the approach I use in my documents and it works out much better, I think.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes, I had it in mind right from the start. And you added the comment anyway :-P

Comment: If that's the order, why is it better with `[]`?

Comment: @Manuel: The usual order is `[]{}` ... I explicitly wanted to reverse this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I mean, if you said *better `\set[..]{..}` than `\set{..}{..}`* I would think “well, that's okey” but if you say *`\set{..}[..]` is better than `\set{..}{..}`*, well, I don't understand why (and I don't think so, at least at this moment I don't see any reason why it would be better).

Comment: @Manuel: It's easier to distinguish between the optional and the mandatory argument, isn't it. Remember which `{}` of the two pairs is difficult, for example, if one does not use this command very often.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The thing about that macro you wrote is that, to the user, there's no optional argument (they needn't to think about it) just write one or two arguments. I did not understand your sentence: *Remember which {} of the two pairs is difficult*. What is difficult?

Comment: @Manuel: The second `{}` is meant for the `conditional` set listing. If this is omitted, it acts just as the listed set. And if the O.P. is happy with this syntax -- nobody is forced to use it

Answer (score 9):

You can do it, but I discourage you to. Better defining a command that distinguishes between `\set{1,2,3}` and `\set{x|<condition>}`.

You can find perhaps better methods in the documentation of `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\set}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{\printset#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printset}{mm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {% no |
    \{#1\}%
   }
   {% |
    \{\,#1\mid#2\,\}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

$\set{1,2,3}=\set{x | 1\le x\le 3}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Took the idea right from my mind :)

Comment: @egreg: You  forgot x to be a natural number :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's obvious from the context, isn't it? `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: In the context yes, but having the RHS as a standalone ...

Answer (score 6):

Here is another soultion, with optional argument

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\set}[2][]{\left\lbrace\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else#1\mid\fi#2\right\rbrace}

\begin{document}
bla bla
\[\set{a,b,c},\set[x]{x>0}\]
$\set{a,b,c},\set[x]{x>0}$
\end{document}
```

**Classical method**

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\set}{\@ifnextchar[{\@@set}{\@set}}
\def\@set#1{\left\lbrace#1\right\rbrace}
\def\@@set[#1]#2{\@set{#1\mid#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
bla bla
\[\set{a,b,c},\set[x]{x>0}\]
$\set{a,b,c},\set[x]{x>0}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no package required. This is good!

Comment: @SayOL that's why i add it

Comment: `\ifx#1\empty` is conceptually wrong. `\ifx#1\empty\relax` would be a little better; `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is the right one.

Comment: @egreg what about `\newcommand{\set}[2][\relax]{\left\lbrace\ifx #1\relax`?

Comment: @touhami Try `\set[aa]{xx}`

Comment: @egreg can you please check the 2nd solution

Answer (score 5):

A variant solution, also with `mathtools` and `xparse`. When used for a set defined by a property, the separator between elements and properties is  a `semicolon`, because it is easy to type, and rarely used in maths (except for sets defined by a property). The resulting sign in the .pdf file will be a vertical bar, with a correct spacing. If for some reason you really  need a semi-colon, you just enclose it between a pair of braces. Thus the syntax is very close to what one writes by hand: `\set{x;P(x)}`.

The size of the braces and the the vertical bar will adjust automatically to the size of the contents with the star version of the `\set` command, or manually for fine-tining, with optional arguments: `\big, \Big, \bigg,`\Bigg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}
%
% %% The following makes \big the default for the \set command
% \let\oldset\set
% \def\set{\futurelet\testchar\MaybeOptArgSet}
% \def\MaybeOptArgSet{\ifx[\testchar \let\next\OptArgSet
% \else \let\next\NoOptArgSet \fi \next}
% \def\OptArgSet[#1]#2{\oldset[#1]{#2}}
% \def\NoOptArgSet#1{\OptArgSet[\big]{#1}}
%
% \def\Set{\oldset*}%

%%% Syntax: \set{x ; P(x)})
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    & \set[\big]{x ; x > 5} & & \set*{x ; x > 5} \\[4pt]
    & \set[\bigg]{ \frac{x}{2} ; x > 5} & & \set*{ \frac{x}{2} ; x > 5} \\[4pt]
    & \set[\Bigg]{ \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dotsm} & & \set*{ \mfrac{1}{2},\mfrac{1}{3},\mfrac{1}{4},\dotsm}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In the above code I commented out some lines that result in the default implicit use of the `\big` optional argument (which looks better, in my opinion). The `\set*` command is the replaced with a new `Set` command.

[image]