# \newcommand with options

Tags: macros, braces, options

My question is about declaring a "newcommand" with an option.

I have defined

```
\newcommand{\bforall}[2]{\forall #1\, (#2)}
```

so that `$\bforall{x}{x \in A}$` writes `$\forall x (x \in A)$`.

I would like some control over the brackets. Namely, I would like

```
\bforall[s]{x}{x \in A}
```

to use square braces, and

```
\bforall[c]{x}{x \in A}
```

to use curly braces.

How can this be accomplished?

I've search the forum and found
1/ [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument)
and
2/ [Optional argument for newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58628/optional-argument-for-newcommand)
and neither helped me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different command definitions with and without optional argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308/different-command-definitions-with-and-without-optional-argument)

Comment: That question deals with the creation of optional ARGUMENTS and not this type of "switch" that i'm trying to create.

Moreover, I indicated that link was unhelpful for me in my question.

Comment: please see @egreg comment to my answer. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254158/new-command-with-two-definitions/254164#254164

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a way, without packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\bforall[3][r]{%
  \ifx r#1\forall #2\, (#3)\else
  \ifx s#1\forall #2\, [#3]\else
  \ifx c#1\forall #2\, \{#3\}\else
  \mathrm{Illegal~option}%
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\begin{document}
$\bforall{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[r]{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[s]{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[c]{x}{x \in A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As touhami rightly points out, the penalty for using the simplicity of the `\ifx` construct is that an accidental syntax error such as using a two character optional argument like `[rs]` will not produce an error message, but rather just wrongly set the term.

Comment: see @egreg comment to my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254158/new-command-with-two-definitions/254164#254164

Comment: @touhami I see the point, but I'm not sure if it applies, since my optional argument has a default non-empty value.  To run into the problem, one would have to pass a blank optional argument, I think.  But it certainly doesn't hurt to add a `\relax` after `#1` to address that case.  In fact, I just tried the case, and it throws the expected error already.

Comment: Sorry, i mean @egreg's last comment, in this case `$\bforall[rs]{x}{x \in A}$`

Comment: @touhami In your case, the optional argument was a mathematical term that could be one or more characters.  In my case, the optional argument is a single letter indicating `r`ound, `s`quare, or `c`urly braces.  A 2-character optional argument in my case is indicative of a syntax error.

Comment: here is the prolem `$\bforall[rs]{x}{x \in A}$` will not idicate error.

Comment: @touhami I have edited my answer to note your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do that using the [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package's `\IfStrEqCase`:

[image]

The default option is `r`ound braces, `c`urly braces and `s`quare braces.  You can also add an optional second parameter to control the brace size:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\bforall}[3][r]{%
    \forall #2\, 
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {r}{(#3)}%
        {c}{\{#3\}}%
        {s}{{[#3]}}%
    }[%
        %% Issue error message here about unsuported bracket type
    ]%
}

\begin{document}
$\bforall{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[r]{x}{x \in A}$


$\bforall[c]{x}{x \in A}$


$\bforall[s]{x}{x \in A}$

\end{document}
```

### Code `Resizing Brackets`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bforall}{%
    O{r}% #1 = r, c or s (bracket shape)
    O{}%  #2 = optional size specifier
    m%    #3
    m%    #4
}{%
    \forall #3\, 
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {r}{#2(#4#2)}%
        {c}{#2\{#4#2\}}%
        {s}{{#2[#4#2]}}%
    }[%
        %% Issue error message here about unsupported bracket type
        \PackageError{tree}{Undefined option to tree: #1}{}
    ]%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
$\bforall{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[r]{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[c]{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[s]{x}{x \in A}$
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\linewidth}
$\bforall[r][\Big]{x}{x \in A, x > \dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\bforall[c][\Big]{x}{x \in A, x > \dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\bforall[s][\bigg]{x}{x \in A, x > \dfrac{1}{2}}$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a case switch macro the best is `expl3`; I used the letters already common with `amsmath`, `p` for parentheses, `b` for brackets, `B` for braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\bforall}{O{p}mm}
 {
  \forall #2\,
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {p}{(#3)}
    {b}{[#3]}
    {B}{\{#3\}}
   }
   {\@latex@error{Illegal~option~#1}{I~used~p}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\bforall{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[p]{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[b]{x}{x \in A}$

$\bforall[B]{x}{x \in A}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A plain TeX one with a different syntax

```
\def\bforall#1{\forall#1\,\futurelet\tmptoken\dobforall}
\def\dobforall{\ifx\tmptoken\bgroup\expandafter\bforallbraces\fi
               \ifx\tmptoken[\expandafter\bforallbrackets\fi
               \ifx\tmptoken(\expandafter\bforallparenthesis\fi
               \relax}
\def\bforallbraces#1\relax#2{\{#2\}}
\def\bforallbrackets#1\relax[#2]{[#2]}
\def\bforallparenthesis#1\relax(#2){(#2)}

$\bforall{x}(x \in A)$\par
$\bforall{x}{x \in A}$\par
$\bforall{x}[x \in A]$\par

\bye
```

[image]

You can use those definitions also in LaTeX without the need of any package. The syntax seems easier for me `\bforall{x}(x\in A)`, `\bforall{x}{x\in A}` and `\bforall{x}[x\in A]`. In any case, for your needs, may be you don't need that macro at all, just `\def\bforall#1{\forall#1\,}` and then it's followed by whatever you input?

---

With a little bit of refinement to let you use `\bforall x {x \in A}` syntax. (In LaTeX it would be easier because of `\@ifnextchar`.)

```
\def\bforall#1{\forall#1\,\futurelet\tmptoken\dobforall}
\def\dobforall{\ifx\tmptoken\spacetoken\expandafter\bforallspace\fi
               \ifx\tmptoken\bgroup\expandafter\bforallbraces\fi
               \ifx\tmptoken[\expandafter\bforallbrackets\fi
               \ifx\tmptoken(\expandafter\bforallparenthesis\fi
               \relax}
\def\bforallbraces#1\relax#2{\{#2\}}
\def\bforallbrackets#1\relax[#2]{[#2]}
\def\bforallparenthesis#1\relax(#2){(#2)}
\def\bforallspace#1\relax{\dobforallspace}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\dobforallspace\space{\futurelet\tmptoken\dobforall}
\lowercase{\let\spacetoken= } %

$\bforall x (x \in A)$\par
$\bforall x {x \in A}$\par
$\bforall x [x \in A]$\par

\bye
```