# Forcing LaTeX to adjust ':' spacing to match \colon

Tags: spacing

As discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas), mathematical functions should be defined using `\colon`, while set definitions should be done using `:`. My problem is that I define functions about twenty times more often that I define sets, and typing out `\colon` every time is a serious overhead; it makes my code much less readable, and it incurs some mental overhead every time that slows down note-taking.

I already prefer the `|` notation for defining sets over `:`, so the default `:` has no use for me. Is it possible to redefine it so it behaves just like `\colon` does?

Comment: `\catcode\`\:=\active 
\def:{\ifmmode\colon\else\char58\fi}`.  This will break other constructs, if they rely on `:` as part of the syntax (though none come to mind at the moment).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm sad hhline didn't come to mind:-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This seems to break equation labels, which I write as “eq:blah”.

Comment: Indeed.  As I noted, "This will break other constructs, if they rely on `:` as part of the syntax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `amsmath`, that you probably are using, `\colon` is not simply a punctuation symbol, but uses a somewhat different spacing (line 3 is what you'd get without `amsmath`).

In line 4 I use `\relcolon` for the set denotation.

***Caution*** This will break with `babel-french`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% a colon as ordinary symbol
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathordcolon}{\mathord}{operators}{"3A}

% a colon as relation symbol
\DeclareMathSymbol{\relcolon}{\mathrel}{operators}{"3A}

% the definition of \colon in amsmath contains :
% which would start an infinite loop
\patchcmd{\colon}{:}{\mathordcolon}{}{}

% provide a definition of : as an active character
\begingroup\lccode`~=`: \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\colon

% make : math active
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`:="8000 }

\begin{document}

1. $f\colon A\to B$ with \verb|\colon|

2. $f:A\to B$ with \verb|:|

3. $f\mathpunct{\mathordcolon} A\to B$

4. $\{\,x\in X\relcolon x=x\}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Warning for others: this conflicts with `mathtools`, in which case the name `ordinarycolon` must be changed.

Comment: @knzhou I forgot about that; better change the name, then.

Answer (score 2):

The following example first shows the original behavior of `:` and `\colon`. Then the relational colon is saved as command `\relcolon` and the colon symbol is reassigned as punctuation colon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  a\colon b:c
\]
%
\mathchardef\relcolon=\mathcode`\:
\mathcode`\:=\colon
%
\[
  a:b\relcolon c
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Is it possible to run this code in a .sty file, or does it need to be inside the document itself?

Comment: @knzhou It can be put in a package file.

Comment: When I place this right into my .sty file I get several errors, starting with `Missing number, treated as zero. [\mathcode\`\:=\colon],  Missing $ inserted. [\mathcode\`\:=\colon]`. Is there something I need to adjust?

Comment: Ah, I see, I think this solution is incompatible with `amsmath`.

Comment: @knzhou This is already addressed by egreg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not strictly answering the question but rather than playing with `:` for sets and functions I, instead, have a `\set{...}` macro (from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209863), and a `\map` macro to achieve similar outcomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209863
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]{\{}{\}}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1} {#1\,\delimsize|\,\mathopen{}#2}}

\newcommand\map[1]{\colon #1\longrightarrow}

\begin{document}

  \verb+$\set{1,2,\dots,n}$+
  $\set{1,2,\dots,n}$

  \verb+$\set{1\le k\le n|k\in\mathbb{Z}}$+
  $\set{1\le k\le n|k\in\mathbb{Z}}$

  \verb+$\set[\Bigg]{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n| 1\le n\le 100}$+

  $\set[\Bigg]{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n| 1\le n\le 100}$

  \verb+$f\map AB$+
  $f\map AB$

   \verb+$f\map{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R}$+
   $f\map{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{R}$

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

As I prefer using `\longrightarrow` to `\to`, typing `\map` is much better than typing `\colon` and then `\longrightarrow`. The other advantage is that both `\set` and `\map` look very close to the mathematical meaning.