# Different horizontal (!) spacing of delimiters with `\left`, `\bigl`, `\Bigl`,

Tags: spacing, amsmath, delimiters

I use `\arrowvert` as a middle delimiter. For example in the definition of sets, i.e. `\lbrace x \arrowvert x < a \rbrace`. Moreover, I try to avoid `\left`, `\right` and `\middle` but use the AMSmath macros `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, ... to set the size explicitly.

If I need the delimiters in "normal" size, I do not use any macro, but then I notice a different horizontal (!) spacing. Consider the case in that `\left`, `\right` and `\middle` can be used without effect, because all enclosed symbols have at most normal size. Then

```
\lbrace x \arrowvert x < a \rbrace

\left\lbrace x \middle\arrowvert x < a \right\rbrace
```

look the same vertically, but there is a little bit more horizontal space of both sides of the middle delimiter. Actually, the visual appearance of the latter looks more correct.

The same amount of additional space around the middle delimiter is inserted by the AMSmath keywords `\big`, `\Big`, ...

But what shall I do, if I need the normally sized delimiters but cannot use the triplet `\left`, `\middle`, `\right` because there is some over-sized content?

Using no macro as suggested by the AMSmath manual is no option, because then the additional space around the middle delimter is missing. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be something like a `\normall`, `\normal`, `\normalr` triplet that does no scaling but fits the horizontal spacing of the other macros.

Comment: Does `\mid` do what you want? (in normally sized)

Comment: No. `\mid` is a binary operator and has a totally different spacing. Actually one should never use `\mid` in this context because it has the wrong class-code. But even if one would not care of correct class-codes and only consider correct visual appearance, `\mid` looks totally different. `\arrowvert`, `\vert`, `\bracevert` and just `|` are all (middle) delimiters (with different "thickness"). I can see this slight different behaviour with all of them.

Comment: You should look at the documentation of `mathtools`, in particular to `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498/mid-vertical-bar-vert-lvert-rvert-divides

Comment: @nagmat84 You're wrong about `\mid`, which is a *relation* symbol, so it's the right kind. The difference is that `\arrowvert` is arbitrarily extendable, which `\mid` isn't; but `\mid` has rounded ends, while `\arrowvert` has sharp ends.

Comment: Just to extend on @egregs suggestion, you could modify the update in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13637/3929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, that's a different question. Unfortunately, a math symbol can be either of class mathopen or mathclose, but not both at the same time.

But the following construction should do:

```
\mathclose{\arrowvert}\mathopen{}
```

for an equivalent to \middle\arrowvert. I tested it and on my screen it looks the same. But, since \arrowvert is of type mathord (and not mathrel, as I suspected previously), the direct use of \arrowvert also is really close in its look to \middle\arrowvert.

Answer (score 0):

Note the exact behaviour of \middle in eTeX as spelled out in the reference (http://archiv.dante.de/projects/nts/archiv/etex-ref-prel.html#middle):

> analogous to TeX's \left and \right, \middle specifies that the
>   following  delimiter is to serve both as a right and left delimiter;
>   it will be set with spacing appropriate to a right delimiter w.r.t.
>   the preceding atom(s), and with spacing appropriate to a left
>   delimiter w.r.t. the succeeding atom(s).

You see, that \middle itself does not behave as a mathematical relation. You can force it to do so by adding \mathrel:

```
\mathrel{}\middle\arrowvert\mathrel{}
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Did you actually test this? `\mathrel` hides `\middle` from `\left...\right`.

Comment: Are you meaning `\mathrel{}\middle\arrowvert\mathrel{}`, perhaps?

Comment: I do not want `\middle` to behave like a relation, the pre-defined behaviour with horizontal spacing to the left like a right delimiter and vice versa is totally correct. I need a naked `\arrowvert` to behave like a `\middle\arrowvert`, `\big\arrowvert` and so on. A naked `\arrowvert` is necesssary, if I need a middle delimiter without sizing adjustment. Hence, either I need `\arrowvert` to behave like a middle delimiter on its own or I need a new `\normalmiddle` command that makes a following `\arrowvert` behave like a delimiter without sizing correction.

Comment: @nagmat84 Do you mean `{\arrowvert}` (with the braces)?