# Missing delimiter inserted in mathcal

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, mathtools

I have code like:

```
N examples,each (input $x_n$, label $y_n$) $\in\mathcal{X} x\left{1,2,\dots,K,\right}$ and cost matrix $C\in\R^{KxK}$
```

Which I am using to replicate:

[image]

But for some reason the code is not rendering - I am using `amsmath`. The error I get is:

Comment: You need `\left\{` and `\right\}` (note the backslash before the curly brackets). *However* just `\{` and `\}` alone (no `\left` and `\right`) would be preferable here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main issue is that you need `\left\{` and `\right\}` (note the `\` before the curly brackets). *However* just `\{` and `\}` alone (no `\left` and `\right`) would be preferable here. See these questions for more:

- [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If you fix this problem, your code will compile (assuming you have already defined `\R` as `\mathbb{R}` - it is not defined by default). However, there are other problems with your code, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent% just for the example
$N$ examples, each $\text{(input $\mathbf{x}_{n}$, label $y_{n}$)} \in
\mathcal{X} \times \{1, 2, \dots, K\}$
\[
  \boxed{\text{and cost matrix $\mathcal{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times K}$}}
\]
---will assume
$\mathcal{C}(y, y) = \green{0} = \min_{1 \leq k \leq K} \mathcal{C}(y,
k)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your main problem is using `x` for `\times`.

For more information on why you were getting an error, allow me to plug my own answer over here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253082/16968. Because `\left` and `\right` require a printable delimiter after them, you need to use `\{` and `\}` (which produce the { and } delimiters) not `{` and `}` which are used to delimit arguments to LaTeX commands not to print delimiters in the actual output.

Comment: I removed the call to the package `parskip`, that's not necessary for the code. Its presence could be misunderstood as essential for solving the OP's issue, besides being a disputable typographic practice.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I just found it the easiest way to reproduce the clear line above and below the boxed line in the OP's example, but your approach is good :)